# Подходы при разработке админ части

Tags: javascript, html, php

В Админке должна быть возможность редактировать, добавлять и изменять:

- Новости
- Публикации
- Исследования
- Кружки
- Курсовые
- Методички и т.д

Всё это будет иметь возможность сохраняться не перезагружая страницы, так же добавляться.
Решил создать 1 файл **ajax_js.js**, который подключаю, и в зависимости от типа контента, допустим 
для новостей

```
 ["id_news=1$title=privet&text=textcacatery"]
```

для публикации

```
["id_pub=2&id_owner=3&date=12-12-2014&pub=1"]
```

и т.д.
Так вот, лучше под каждый тим понтента(около 9 -15) создать отдельный **js с ajax-запросом** настроенным специально под данный тип контента, или лучше в 1-м файле, но через большое кол-во IF-фов? 
Мое мнение, лучше под каждый тип контента отдельно создать файл, и только его загружать, будет проще работать, если нужно что-либо будет изменить, да и файл меньше гораздо весить будет.

Comment: Пиши js код прямо там в шаблонах )

Answer (score 2):

Извините, но вы здесь написали полную чушь. Не мудрите, делайте все проще. Отправляйте AJAX POST запрос из формы добавления, допустим, новости на файл-обработчик добавления новости (допустим, add_news.php) и в нем уже проверяйте присутствие данных в массиве $_POST, валидируйте их и добавляйте в таблицу в БД.